# Oracle PL/SQL how to reassign the result of a substitution variable to a new variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql, substitution

I am having a small issue trying to use substitution variables for table names.  When I run the below code with a `QTR_END` date of `31-DEC-2009`, I get an error because instead of `QUARTER = 4`, and `ACCYEAR = 2009`, it tries to create a table with the name of:

`"ZZ_PLANNING_DATA_TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Q'))QTO_NUMBER(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY')))"`

Of course I am trying to create a table `"ZZ_PLANNING_DATA_4Q2009"`

I don't know how to force the substitution variables to substitute their executed value, instead of just substituting the code. ?

```
ACCEPT QTR_END DATE PROMPT 'Enter the last day of the period you wish to run (i.e.: 30-JUN-2014).';

DEFINE QUARTER = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Q'));
DEFINE ACCYEAR = TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY')));

DEFINE BACKUP_TABLE_NAME = "ZZ_PLANNING_DATA_&&QUARTER.Q&&ACCYEAR";
CREATE TABLE &&BACKUP_TABLE_NAME COMPRESS NOLOGGING
AS SELECT * FROM ZZ_PLANNING_DATA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ACCEPT QTR_END DATE PROMPT 'Enter the last day of the period you wish to run (i.e.: 30-JUN-2014).';

col quarter form a30 new_value quarter
col accyear form a30 new_value accyear

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Q') quarter,
       TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'))) accyear
from dual;

DEFINE BACKUP_TABLE_NAME = ZZ_PLANNING_DATA_&&QUARTER.Q&&ACCYEAR

prompt quarter: &quarter 
prompt accyear: &accyear
prompt backup_table_name: &backup_table_name

CREATE TABLE &&BACKUP_TABLE_NAME COMPRESS NOLOGGING
AS SELECT * FROM ZZ_PLANNING_DATA;
```

Or, easier I reckon to do it in PLSQL:

```
ACCEPT QTR_END DATE PROMPT 'Enter the last day of the period you wish to run (i.e.: 30-JUN-2014).';

declare
  quarter VARCHAR2(6) := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Q');
  accyear VARCHAR2(6) := EXTRACT (YEAR FROM TO_DATE('&&QTR_END','DD-MM-YYYY'));
  backup_name varchar2(30) := 'ZZ_PLANNING_DATA_' || QUARTER || 'Q' || ACCYEAR;
begin
  execute immediate 'create table ' || backup_name || ' as select * from zz_planning_data';
end;
/
```